Internal`HouseKeep function definition
I came across the Internal`HouseKeep[] function. I can't understand exactly how it works. The name of the function is not at all descriptive, but if you call it, it returns a URL with an additional parameter - a digital signature. Does anyone know the method it uses to sign the data? Or maybe there is an implementation of this function in SystemFiles? Example^
Internal`HouseKeep["https://wolfram.com", {}]


https://wolfram.com?appid=<appid>&mlicense=<mylicense>&machineid=><mathid>&sig=df34fe10d6b2845510e028dc27287afe



The purpose of signature is to guarantee the recipient that the data is authentic and has not been altered. There are various possible implementation (for example HMAC), and they usually involve creating a hash of data and a private key. Is there any particular reason you are interested in this particular function (since I don't really believe you can do anything reasonable with it), or do you just want to code a similar solution for some other problem you have? :)

@Domen I know what a digital signature is and have implemented HMAC in some projects. I am interested in the implementation of this function

Sure, but why? It's an internal function used for communication with Wolfram Servers (such as Wolfram Cloud or Wolfram|Alpha). Are you trying to temper with data? :)

I want to implement what this function does in another programming language. I don't need the exact implementation, I just want to understand what signature method is used
